# why does my setInterval is not working in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm trying to create a simple time showing website for practice 
I tried using `setInterval()` but it's not working.

Here's my App.js file

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

function Clock(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <h2>{props.date.toLocaleTimeString()}</h2>
    </>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Clock date={new Date()} />
    </div>
  );
}

setInterval(App, 1000);  {/* setInterval(Clock, 1000) */}

export default App;
```

and Index.js file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a functional component alone doesn't do anything unless you put the resulting element into a `ReactDOM.render` or into another functional component. Your `setInterval(App, 1000);` is doing nothing.

Have the component get itself to rerender instead.

```
function App() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setDate(new Date());
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <Clock date={date} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then the single use of `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));` will result in the clock updating whenever the state changes.

If you ever plan on unmounting the component, it'd also be good to save the interval ID in a variable and return a cleanup function from the effect callback to clear the interval.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setDate(new Date());
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and so I can't achieve without using react hooks?

Comment: Other ways exist, but they're *really really strange* and there's no reason to use them. Use hooks, or `componentDidMount` in a class component

Comment: @CertainPerformance now you have piqued my interest, what are the *really really strange* ways?

Comment: @Nick Like `.remove()`ing the React container and creating another one, or maybe by calling `ReactDOM.render` again (not sure what that would do), or by using vanilla DOM methods to mutate the DOM instead of having the data flow from the React component. Bad ideas all.

Comment: my eyes, I wish I hadn't asked. :)